# Why my C dll are properly imported on Python and not my C++ dll?

Tags: python, c++, dll

OS : Windows 10 64 bits

Python : 3.9.5 64 bits

Compiler : gcc version 8.1.0 (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)

Problem : I don't know so much about Python and I try to import some very basic DLL to start. I don't understand why a C dll is found correctly on my computer while a C++ dll can not be found.

**C code (mini.c) :**

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C" {

        __declspec( dllexport ) void hi() {

                printf("\nHello World from C !\n");

        }

}
```

**C++ code (mini_cpp.cpp) :**

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" {

        __declspec(dllexport) void hi() {

                std::cout << std::endl << "Hello World from C++ !" << std::endl;

        }

}
```

**Makefile and its result :**

```
all: mini.dll mini_cpp.dll

mini.dll: mini.o

        g++ mini.o -shared -Wl,--out-implib,libmini.a -o mini.dll

mini.o: mini.c

        g++ -c mini.c -I . -o mini.o

mini_cpp.dll: mini_cpp.o

        g++ mini_cpp.o -shared -Wl,--out-implib,libmini_cpp.a -o mini_cpp.dll

mini_cpp.o: mini_cpp.cpp

        g++ -c mini_cpp.cpp -I . -o mini_cpp.o


g++ -c mini.c -I . -o mini.o

g++ mini.o -shared -Wl,--out-implib,libmini.a -o mini.dll

g++ -c mini_cpp.cpp -I . -o mini_cpp.o

g++ mini_cpp.o -shared -Wl,--out-implib,libmini_cpp.a -o mini_cpp.dll
```

**Python code and results for the C DLL :**

```
Python 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>>
>>> import ctypes
>>>
>>> from ctypes import *
>>>
>>> my_lib = windll.LoadLibrary( os.path.abspath( "mini.dll") )
>>>
>>> my_func = my_lib.hi
>>>
>>> my_func.restype = c_char_p
>>>
>>> my_func()

Hello World from C !
```

**Python code and results for the C++ DLL :**

```
>>> my_cpp_lib = windll.LoadLibrary( os.path.abspath( "mini_cpp.dll") )

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\AGENT_TI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 452, in LoadLibrary
return self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\Users\AGENT_TI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 374, in __init__
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\Users\AGENT_TI\Desktop\STRINGS\python\mini_cpp.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
>>>
```

~
~
What I have already tried :

- The different os.path operations in Python :

os.chdir("C:\Users\AGENT_TI\Desktop\STRINGS\python")

os.add_dll_directory("C:\Users\AGENT_TI\Desktop\STRINGS\python")

- compiling with gcc instead of g++ (with adding -lstdc++ for the C++ code)

If someone already faced this problem and have some fix, thank you...

Comment: ***"or one of its dependencies"*** - that's probably important here :-) It's always annoyed me that it's apparently so difficult for the loader to not just shove a message like "the culprit was xyzzy.dll" to standard error. Suggest you find a dependency walker tool and investigate which particular library/object cannot be found.

Comment: What happens if building the *.dll* with *-static-libstdc++*?

Answer (score 0):

Paxdiablo : You are right in your assuming of a dll problem (and I am 100 % agree about the lack of precision of the messages leading to such a waste of time)

objdump showed me the following for mini_cpp.dll :

```
DLL Name: libstdc++-6.dll
vma:  Hint/Ord Member-Name Bound-To
9588     1739  _ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E
959c     4448  _ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev
95b8     4450  _ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev
95d4     4738  _ZSt4cout
95e0     4739  _ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_
9620     4847  _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc
```

CristiFati : I didn't try to build the dll statically but I guess it would have worked indeed.

By the way, following your intuitions (and the fact -lstdlibc++ is finally the only difference between my two dlls), I just loaded the library in Python before my dll
and the result is good (despite the spurious characters under my string but I guess it could be fixed in Python later). It explains why attempts to use boost::python or
the Python API was leading to the same problem.

**Modified Python code and result :**

```
>>> import os
>>>
>>> import ctypes
>>>
>>> from ctypes import *
>>>
>>> my_lib = windll.LoadLibrary( os.path.abspath( "mini.dll") )
>>>
>>> my_func = my_lib.hi
>>>
>>> my_func.restype = c_char_p
>>>
>>> my_func()

Hello World from C !
>>>
>>> windll.LoadLibrary("C:\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\lib\\libstdc++-6.dll")
<WinDLL 'C:\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libstdc++-6.dll', handle 6fc40000 at 0x25a1f2ade50>
>>>
>>> my_cpp_lib = windll.LoadLibrary( os.path.abspath( "mini_cpp.dll") )
>>>
>>> my_cpp_func = my_cpp_lib.hi
>>>
>>> my_cpp_func.restype = c_wchar_p
>>>
>>> my_cpp_func()

Hello World from C++ !
'\uf038濑'
>>>
```

Thanks for your help paxdiablo and CristiFati :-)

Comment: Side notes (don't have any functional implication), don't set *restype* of a function returning *void* (or if you want to be explicit set it to *None*). Also, I think *G++* produces *cdecl* functions (in that case *cdll* should be used instead of *windll*), but **this is only relevant on *32bit***.

Comment: Also, I don't know why linking ro static *C++* *lib* "untestable".